# Twitter/Typehead suggestion display inline

Tags: javascript, css, typehead

Is there any option or CSS trick to show typehead suggestions inline ( Like in SO Tags suggestions)?

I tried some css ( display flex, changing width ), but not worked as i expected.

This is the current result,

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L92m7Ldu/23/)

[image]

I need to make it like this

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide more insight into what you're looking for, this is very vague.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by simple css. Suggestions are contained in `tt-menu > tt-dataset` div. You can change the width and set `tt-dataset` div's `display:flex`

```
.tt-menu{
  width: 500 !important;
}

.tt-dataset{
  display:flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates to render data content of a typehead this is a sample code which I have used.

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 3
    }, {
        name: 'Cities',
        source: citiesSubstringMatcher(),
        display: 'name',
        limit: 20,
        templates: {
            suggestion: suggestions_city_html
        }
    });

function suggestions_city_html(data) {
    return "<div class='pointer'>" + data.name + "</div>";
}
```

you can define your own templets for this.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question properly. I have used the template exactly in the images. I just need to position them inline like in second image.